# Pandas - Use loc to access levels of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe with 3 levels in the index that looks like this:

> In: z.index.values[0] 
>   Out: ('AT', 'Paddy rice', 'M.EUR')

There are in total 9800 elements in the index such as for example:

> In: z.index.values[1] 
>   Out: ('AT', 'Wheat', 'M.EUR')

I know that if I do z.loc['AT'] I will get a slice of my dataframe where the index has the value 'AT'.

There are several values in all positions of the tuple and I am struggling in how to access only the second position of the tuple.

How would you slice only on the second position of the tuple? Can you slice with a list?

Thank you

Comment: You want get all values of secon level by `z.index.get_level_values(1)`? Or second value of tuple like `z.index.values[0][1]` ?

Comment: How do you perform .loc with all values of second level only?

Comment: I think `z.xs('Wheat', level=1)` should works.

Comment: Cool! That worked! How would you apply the same but with a list of values instead of a single value?